# Classes calling a common method - delegate?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class

I have a form which creates a BackgroundWorker. The worker then does some work, and does a ReportProgress to send messages back to the UI while it's busy. I then log those messages to the UI. The ReportProgress is done by a single method in the thread, which I called 'Notify'.

However, within the thread, I call a static class to do file access type work. That static class needs to also report progress... so I need to call the Notify method of the thread class that called the static class - but, I have no access to the methods within the calling class.

So, UI creates thread... and thread uses a class, but I need to call the Notify method in the class, from the static class. How can I do this?

This is my attempt to far. The idea is to try use a delegate... but, I am stuck at actually using the delegate. :)

In my thread class, I have a method:

```
public void Notify(string message, Constants.ErrorLevel errorLevel)
{
    var su = new StatusUpdate {StatusMessage = message, ErrorLevel = 0};
    _bw.ReportProgress(0, su);
}
```

This is working. It reports well to the calling UI.

I now created a delegate in this class:

```
public delegate bool NotificationsDelegate(object MessageHolder);
```

I have changed my static class for handing file management, to non-static, and am wanting to pass that delegate to the file manager class when I create it:

```
public class FileManager
{
private readonly NotificationsDelegate _notifications;

public FileManager(NotificationsDelegate notifications)
{
    _notifications = notifications;
}

private void SendMessageBack(string p, ConsoleColor consoleColor)
{
    var su = new StatusUpdate {ErrorLevel = 0, StatusMessage = p};
    _notifications(su);
}
```

So, I create it, and pass the Notification delegate... and then in my 'SendMessageBack' method, hope to call the delegate (called _notifications).

But that's where I am stuck. The delegate isn't assigned to the notify method yet. I'm new to events, so guessing my way around. But, can someone help me get this right?

Comment: Pass the BackgroundWorker to the method in the static class so it can call ReportProgress?

Comment: I was thinking of this, but then on each time I use the static method, I have to add the bw object to each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to share one instance of the FileManager class between threads, then yes you absolutely will have to pass in a delegate instance every time you call it.  If you create a new instance of the FileManager class in each "thread class", then you can just give the FileManager the delegate in the ctor as you have it written.

```
public delegate void NotifyDelegate(string message, Constants.ErrorLevel errorLevel);

public class BackgroundWorker {
    public BackgroundWorker() {
        _fileMgr = new FileManager(Notify);
    }

    public void Notify(string message, Constants.ErrorLevel errorLevel) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class FileManager {
    public FileManager(NotifyDelegate notification) {
        _notification = notification;
    }

    public void SendMessageBack() {
        _notification("foo", 0);
    }
}
```

If you want you can just use lambda's and avoid having to create delegates directly:

```
public class FileManager {
    public FileManager(Action<string, Constants.ErrorLevel> notifyAction) {
        _notification = notifyAction;
    }

    public void SendMessageBack() {
        _notification("foo", 0);
    }
}

public class BackgroundWorker {
    public BackgroundWorker() {
        _fileMgr = new FileManager((a, b) => Notify(a, b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I'm following what you're doing but I'd take a look at an event-based notification system for calling your `Notify` method from your file access work class.  I'm assuming your file access work class is called `FileManager` and that it's an instance class.

First, create a custom `EventArg` class to store the data you want to relay in the notifications coming out of your `FileManager` class.  Create a `DoNotify` event in your `FileManager` class that uses this custom `EventArg` class and call the event (after populating it with your status data) when you wish to update the `Notify` method.

When you instantiate a `FileManager` object subscribe to the `DoNotify` event and in its handler call your `Notify` method:

```
public class FileManager
{
    public event EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs> DoNotify;

    private void DoSomethingInterestingMethod() {
        //...

        // Let listeners know something interesting happened.
        var doNotify = DoNotify;
        if (doNotify != null) {
            doNotify(this, new NotifyEventArgs(errorLevel, message));
        }

       //...
    }
}

public class NotifyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public NotifyEventArgs(int errorLevel, string statusMessage) {
        ErrorLevel = errorLevel;
        StatusMessage = statusMessage;
    }

    public int ErrorLevel { get; private set;}
    public string StatusMessage { get; private set; }
}
```

And then on your BackgroundWorker thread (in `DoWork`(?)) create one ore more `FileManager` objects and subscribe to the `DoNotify` event:

```
var fm = new FileManager();
fm.DoNotify += FileManager_Notify;
```

And in the DoNotify handler call your `Notify` method:

```
void FileManager_Notify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e) {
    Notify(e.ErrorLevel, e.StatusMessage);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure of some of your implementation details so I hope I've made myself clear enough to allow you to evaluate this approach and decide if it's right for you.